# Script will not save value correctly on each iteration and always shows n/a

Tags: pine-script

I currently work on a rather simple indicator script or so I thought.
Unfortunately I can't get a valid value out of my script and I don't know why.

The idea is similiar to Renko-Charts and goes like this.

I will configure a step size and will than calculate how much steps have past from one candle to another.
Here is an example:

[image: Example Chart]

The blue line shows the closing prices and the red line should be my indicator.
The step size is 5.

So for the second candle the calculation should go like this:

Number of changed steps.

Current close - last indicator level = 16 - 10 = 6
Difference / step size = 6 / 5 = 1,2

As only whole steps count the divisional remain gets tossed away so = 1

Current indicator level = last indicator level + ( step size * Number of Changed steps)
= 10 + ( 5 * 1 ) = 15

So my code looks like this:

```
//@version=4

study("My Script", overlay = false)

float myIndicator = 0
float stepSize = 5
int stepNumber = 0

stepNumber := int( ( close - myIndicator[1] ) / stepSize )

myIndicator := myIndicator[1] + ( stepNumber * stepSize )

plot( myIndicator )
```

But it will always show "n/a"
If I change the last line to `myIndicator = close` I can somewhat verify that at least till `stepNumber` calculation everything seems to work. After that something will get invalid but I can't see where I made the mistake...

Does anyone have a tip what I overlook?

Thanks in advance :)

Best regards
Evox

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. Please provide the community with a working example of what you already have. Thank you. Also, if you have a Pro+ or Premium plan, Renko charts are included.

Comment: Hi Bjorn, I updated the code, it should compile now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the very first bar, there is no bar history, so `myIndicator[1]` evaluates to `na`.
The result of a calculation with `na` is always `na`.
Therefore, all your results were `na`.
You can use the [nz()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_nz) function to replace `na` values with zero (that's the default replacement value) or a given value.

This will plot what you're looking for:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

var float   stepSize    = input(5, "stepSize",   minval=0)
var int     stepNumber  = input(0, "stepNumber", minval=0)
var float   myIndicator = na

stepNumber  := int( ( close - nz( myIndicator[1] ) ) / stepSize )
myIndicator := nz( myIndicator[1] ) + ( stepNumber * stepSize )

plot( myIndicator, style=plot.style_stepline )
```

Which yields this on a [daily chart of `AAPL`](https://www.tradingview.com/chart?symbol=NASDAQ%3AAAPL)

[image: AAPL Example]

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I wasn't sure how to initialize it properly so that the -[1] will work correctly.